# How can I get new max list referring to other special index using pandas dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

my data is about measuring the maximum battery life per cycles and degradation model,
and my battery experimental data looks alike this:

These are the structure of my data, stored in csv format:

```
counter cycle mAh
1   1   0
2   1   3.3
3   1   6.6
....
88   1   30.9
89   1   28.3
....
220   1   0
221   2   0
222   2   3.3
....
380   2   29.5
381   2   25.4
....
```

then, how can I collect the max rows for these samples?
[30.9, 29.5, ...] so on?

I've tried these codes but it really didn't work:

```
maxCycle = int(df[['cycle']].max())
print(maxCycle)
cycleList = []
maxList = []

for i in range(maxCycle+1):
    # cycleMax = dfArray.max(axis=0)
    # maxList.append(cycleMax)
    # print(dfArray.[df['cycle']==i])
    print(dfArray.)
```

Comment: Please do not use images and/or external sources. Instead give us a minimal example and I am sure we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with `idxmax`:

```
df.loc[df.groupby("cycle")["mAh"].idxmax()]
```

The output is:

```
   counter  cycle   mAh
3       88      1  30.9
8      380      2  29.5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: This perfectly fits my situation! I really really thank you :)